# WPF is it possible to pass gridname as parameter to checkbox event

Tags: c#, wpf

Am working on a form where I have to disable or enable controls based on two checkboxes. This scenario is required in about 8 different grids. I have done the C# to disable/enable controls and that's working fine. 
Now how do I use the same method across all 8 grids? 
The first option I tried was to get the parent grid but that will fail if it's within another grid.

The other option am thinkg of is to pass the grid as a parameter if possible.
Please let me know if it's feasible and how. Also let me know if there are better ways to achieve this.

**Update:** One thing I forget to mention is the checkboxes shouldn't be disable but all other controls and that's why the C# code behind. Also disabling the entire grid is not the solution.

XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="CatelDemo.Views.Stack"
        Title="Stack" Height="338" Width="644">
    <Grid >
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Name="TabOne">
                <Grid x:Name="GridOne">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbOneGridOne" Checked="cbOne_Checked" Unchecked="cbOne_Checked" />
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbTwoGridOne" Checked="cbOne_Checked" Unchecked="cbOne_Checked" />
                    <!-- Other controls that should be disable-->
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
                <Grid x:Name="GridTwo">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbOneGridTwo" Checked="cbOne_Checked" Unchecked="cbOne_Checked" />
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbTwoGridTwo" Checked="cbOne_Checked" Unchecked="cbOne_Checked" />
                    <!-- Other controls that should be disable-->
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Code, extension methods:

```
public static void DisableAll(this IEnumerable<Control> input, List<String> filter)
        {
            input.Where(c => !filter.Contains(c.Name)).ToList().ForEach(c => c.IsEnabled = false);
        }

        public static void EnableAll(this IEnumerable<Control> input, List<String> filter)
        {
            input.Where(c => !filter.Contains(c.Name)).ToList().ForEach(c => c.IsEnabled = true);
        }
```

Now on the XAML code behind I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
private void cbOne_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var filter = getFilter();
        var isValid = ValidateChecks();
            var controls = sourceGrid.Children.OfType<Control>();
            if (!isValid)
            {
                controls.DisableAll(filter);
            }
            else
            {
                controls.EnableAll(filter);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of the XAML you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just DataBind the checkboxes to a Style that sets the `IsEnabled`-Property and use that style for all the Grids:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType={x:Type Grid}>
        <Style.Triggers>
             <MultiDataTrigger>
                  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                      <Condition Binding="{ElementName=cb1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                      <Condition Binding="{ElementName=cb2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
             </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<CheckBox x:Name="cb1" />
<CheckBox x:Name="cb2" />
```

Either use that style as a resource directly or add a ResourceKey to it and use it per grid explicitly. I've set the style to a `UserControl` but basically you can set that style to a `Window` or even at `App` level if those checkboxes are available - if they are not, bind their IsChecked Property to a DataContext object that you add at the respective level.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a `DataContext` MVVM style and have the grid's `enabled` property bound to the checkboxes `checked` property. You just have to check for them using `Bindings`

Comment: I have already achieved that and remember in the quesiton I said I wanted same method applicable to different grids having diffent DataContexts. Also not the entire grid should be disable but some of the controls.